# Mapply statement is returning incorrect value. What is happening?

Tags: r, mapply

I'm trying to create a new column in my data frame. This column requires using 2 values from the current row and uses them to look up a specific value in another data frame -- that specific value will be inserted in the current row under the new column. I'm running into trouble and getting incorrect values in the new column.

I will illustrate below.

Below is my data frame that I am adding a column. I am trying to use a Mapply statement to create a new column (winner_adv) that contains the advantage multiplier based on winner_type.1 and loser_type.1.

```
First_pokemon         Second_pokemon    Winner                  Loser diff_hp diff_att diff_def diff_sp.att diff_sp.def diff_speed winner_type.1 winner_type.2 loser_type.1 loser_type.2
1      Larvitar                Nuzleaf   Nuzleaf               Larvitar      20        6      -10          15         -10         19         Grass          Dark         Rock       Ground
2      Virizion              Terrakion Terrakion               Virizion       0       39       18         -18         -39          0          Rock      Fighting        Grass     Fighting
3       Togetic               Beheeyem  Beheeyem                Togetic      20       35      -10          45         -10          0       Psychic                      Fairy       Flying
4        Slugma              Druddigon Druddigon                 Slugma      37       80       50         -10          50         28        Dragon                       Fire             
5       Omastar                Shuckle   Omastar                Shuckle      50       50     -105         105        -160         50          Rock         Water          Bug         Rock
```

So, I run the following statement. Where "battles" is my original data frame, seen above.

```
battles$winner_adv <- mapply(findAdv, battles$winner_type.1, battles$loser_type.1)

findAdv <- function(t1, t2) {
  return(typechart[t1, t2])
}
```

It transforms my "battles" data frame into this.

```
First_pokemon         Second_pokemon    Winner                  Loser diff_hp diff_att diff_def diff_sp.att diff_sp.def diff_speed winner_type.1 winner_type.2 loser_type.1 loser_type.2 winner_adv
1      Larvitar                Nuzleaf   Nuzleaf               Larvitar      20        6      -10          15         -10         19         Grass          Dark         Rock       Ground        1.0
2      Virizion              Terrakion Terrakion               Virizion       0       39       18         -18         -39          0          Rock      Fighting        Grass     Fighting        1.0
3       Togetic               Beheeyem  Beheeyem                Togetic      20       35      -10          45         -10          0       Psychic                      Fairy       Flying        1.0
4        Slugma              Druddigon Druddigon                 Slugma      37       80       50         -10          50         28        Dragon                       Fire                     1.0
5       Omastar                Shuckle   Omastar                Shuckle      50       50     -105         105        -160         50          Rock         Water          Bug         Rock        1.0
6        Joltik Aegislash Shield Forme    Joltik Aegislash Shield Forme     -10       -3     -100           7        -100          5           Bug      Electric        Steel        Ghost        0.5
```

But, the first value in the "winner_adv" column is wrong. It is looking into another data frame, (typechart) to get the values. It's shown below.

```
Normal Fire Water Electric Grass Ice Fighting Poison Ground Flying Psychic Bug Rock Ghost Dragon Dark Steel Fairy
Normal        1  1.0   1.0      1.0   1.0 1.0        1    1.0      1    1.0       1 1.0  0.5     0    1.0    1   0.5     1
Fire          1  0.5   0.5      1.0   2.0 2.0        1    1.0      1    1.0       1 2.0  0.5     1    0.5    1   2.0     1
Water         1  2.0   0.5      1.0   0.5 1.0        1    1.0      2    1.0       1 1.0  2.0     1    0.5    1   1.0     1
Electric      1  1.0   2.0      0.5   0.5 1.0        1    1.0      0    2.0       1 1.0  1.0     1    0.5    1   1.0     1
Grass         1  0.5   2.0      1.0   0.5 1.0        1    0.5      2    0.5       1 0.5  2.0     1    0.5    1   0.5     1
Ice           1  0.5   0.5      1.0   2.0 0.5        1    1.0      2    2.0       1 1.0  1.0     1    2.0    1   0.5     1
```

This means, in the first row of the "battles" data frame -- the "winner_adv" value should be:

```
typechart["Grass", "Rock"]
[1] 2
```

But it's returning 1.0 via the Mapply statement. I am unsure why this is occurring.

Here are data types of the "battles" data frame. Followed by data types of "typchart".

```
 $ First_pokemon : Factor w/ 800 levels "","Abomasnow",..: 350 753 712 649 507 314 488 380 536 776 ...
 $ Second_pokemon: Factor w/ 800 levels "","Abomasnow",..: 503 704 47 164 629 7 316 238 103 534 ...
 $ Winner        : Factor w/ 800 levels "","Abomasnow",..: 503 704 47 164 507 314 316 238 103 534 ...
 $ Loser         : Factor w/ 800 levels "","Abomasnow",..: 350 753 712 649 629 7 488 380 536 776 ...
 $ diff_hp       : int  20 0 20 37 50 -10 25 80 0 -5 ...
 $ diff_att      : int  6 39 35 80 50 -3 0 20 -12 25 ...
 $ diff_def      : int  -10 18 -10 50 -105 -100 -10 70 -28 10 ...
 $ diff_sp.att   : int  15 -18 45 -10 105 7 45 65 23 -5 ...
 $ diff_sp.def   : int  -10 -39 -10 50 -160 -100 50 85 28 20 ...
 $ diff_speed    : int  19 0 0 28 50 5 25 55 29 5 ...
 $ winner_type.1 : Factor w/ 18 levels "Bug","Dark","Dragon",..: 10 16 15 3 16 1 12 9 18 4 ...
 $ winner_type.2 : Factor w/ 19 levels "","Bug","Dark",..: 3 7 1 1 19 5 16 4 1 1 ...
 $ loser_type.1  : Factor w/ 18 levels "Bug","Dark","Dragon",..: 16 10 5 7 1 17 15 6 1 18 ...
 $ loser_type.2  : Factor w/ 19 levels "","Bug","Dark",..: 12 7 9 1 17 10 9 1 1 9 ...
 $ winner_adv    : num  1 1 1 1 1 0.5 1 1 1 1 ...
```

```
$ Normal  : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ Fire    : num  1 0.5 2 1 0.5 0.5 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ Water   : num  1 0.5 0.5 2 2 0.5 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Electric: num  1 1 1 0.5 1 1 1 1 2 0.5 ...
 $ Grass   : num  1 2 0.5 0.5 0.5 2 1 2 0.5 2 ...
 $ Ice     : num  1 2 1 1 1 0.5 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ Fighting: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ Poison  : num  1 1 1 1 0.5 1 0.5 0.5 2 1 ...
 $ Ground  : num  1 1 2 0 2 2 1 0.5 1 1 ...
 $ Flying  : num  1 1 1 2 0.5 2 0.5 1 0 1 ...
 $ Psychic : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 0.5 1 1 1 ...
 $ Bug     : num  1 2 1 1 0.5 1 0.5 1 0.5 2 ...
 $ Rock    : num  0.5 0.5 2 1 2 1 2 0.5 2 0.5 ...
 $ Ghost   : num  0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0.5 1 1 ...
 $ Dragon  : num  1 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Dark    : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ Steel   : num  0.5 2 1 1 0.5 0.5 2 0 2 0.5 ...
 $ Fairy   : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 0.5 2 1 1 ...
```

Comment: Can you please supply `dput(battles)` so we can see the data types involved? What version of R are you using?

Comment: Also post the output of `dput(typechart)` please. Or, if the data frames are too big, of `dput(head(battles, 20))` and `dput(head(typechart, 20))`.

Comment: @MrFlick, let me know if that helps

Comment: *Please*, `dput`.

Comment: @r2evans, having trouble uploading dput output -- lots of characters even when I use head(battles, 1). One second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up front:

```r
findAdv <- function(t1, t2) {
  return(typechart[as.character(t1), as.character(t2)])
}
```

`factor`s are your problem here.

```r
findAdv <- function(t1, t2) {
  browser()
  return(typechart[t1, t2])
}

> mapply(findAdv, battles$winner_type.1, battles$loser_type.1)
Called from: (function(t1, t2) {
  browser()
  return(typechart[t1, t2])
  ...
Browse[1]> debug at #3: return(typechart[t1, t2])
Browse[2]> t1
[1] Grass
Levels: Dragon Grass Psychic Rock
Browse[2]> t2
[1] Rock
Levels: Bug Fairy Fire Grass Rock
Browse[2]> c(t1,t2)
[1] 2 5                                            # <--- here's a hint
Browse[2]> typechart[t1, t2]
[1] 2
Browse[2]> typechart[as.character(t1), as.character(t2)]
[1] 2
```

At this point, realize that `typechart[2,5]` (which is not Grass/Rock) is the same *value* as `typechart["Grass","Rock"]`, but it is not the same location in the `typechart` matrix. Coincidence. Let's go to the second iteration by pressing `c`ontinue.

```r
Browse[2]> c
Browse[2]> Called from: (function(t1, t2) {
  browser()
  return(typechart[t1, t2])
  ...
Browse[1]> debug at #3: return(typechart[t1, t2])
Browse[2]> c(t1,t2)
[1] 4 4
Browse[2]> typechart[t1, t2]
[1] 0.5
Browse[2]> typechart[as.character(t1), as.character(t2)]
Error in typechart[as.character(t1), as.character(t2)] (from #3) : 
  subscript out of bounds
    x
 1. \-base::mapply(findAdv, battles$winner_type.1, battles$loser_type.1)
 2.   \-(function (t1, t2) ...
Browse[2]> c(as.character(t1), as.character(t2))
[1] "Rock"  "Grass"
```

It is producing an error because your sample data is incomplete: while we have at least 4 rows and 4 columns (when using the integer format of the `factor`s), we do not have a row for `"Rock"`.

In *your* data, I would expect that this would not produce an error, but would instead give you a different lookup value.

---

Data:

```r
battles <- structure(list(First_pokemon = structure(c(1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Larvitar", "Omastar", "Slugma", "Togetic", "Virizion"), class = "factor"), Second_pokemon = structure(c(3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("Beheeyem", "Druddigon", "Nuzleaf", "Shuckle", "Terrakion"), class = "factor"), Winner = structure(c(3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("Beheeyem", "Druddigon", "Nuzleaf", "Omastar", "Terrakion"), class = "factor"), Loser = structure(c(1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Larvitar", "Shuckle", "Slugma", "Togetic", "Virizion"), class = "factor"), diff_hp = c(20L, 0L, 20L, 37L, 50L), diff_att = c(6L, 39L, 35L, 80L, 50L), diff_def = c(-10L, 18L, -10L, 50L, -105L), diff_sp.att = c(15L, -18L, 45L, -10L, 105L), diff_sp.def = c(-10L, -39L, -10L, 50L, -160L), diff_speed = c(19L, 0L, 0L, 28L, 50L), winner_type.1 = structure(c(2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("Dragon", "Grass", "Psychic", "Rock"), class = "factor"),     winner_type.2 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c(".",     "Dark", "Fighting", "Water"), class = "factor"), loser_type.1 = structure(c(5L,     4L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Bug", "Fairy", "Fire", "Grass",     "Rock"), class = "factor"), loser_type.2 = structure(c(4L,     2L, 3L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c(".", "Fighting", "Flying", "Ground",     "Rock"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
typechart <- structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 2, 2, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0.5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 2, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), .Dim = c(6L, 18L), .Dimnames = list(c("Normal", "Fire", "Water", "Electric", "Grass", "Ice"), c("Normal", "Fire", "Water", "Electric", "Grass", "Ice", "Fighting", "Poison", "Ground", "Flying", "Psychic", "Bug", "Rock", "Ghost", "Dragon", "Dark", "Steel", "Fairy")))
```